# Replace occasional Space with Underscore using Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I am creating a model which will give me two string values, one which reads exactly what is in a field and another which automatically replaces any Space with an "_". I have used Calculate Value tool, and entered in the following:

Expression:

```
ReplaceName(%Value%)
```

Code Block:

```
def ReplaceName(name):
 return name.replace(" ", "_")
```

The result is an error:

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: ReplaceName(NoSpace1) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NoSpace1' is not defined
```

I suspect because not all my Values have spaces

[image: Model and table]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant of fixes, but it did work:

[image]

I found that the %Value% had to have Quotes and I used a try/except sequence to get around the possible lack of a space in some of the values.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily have to define a function for this one. Try this:

```
str(!PlaceName!).replace(' ', '')
```

The "not defined" error is related to the lack of quotes around the NoSpace1. This could be from the % on either side of the Value. Your expression should be

```
ReplaceName(!Placename!)
```

Comment: or `str(!PlaceName!).replace(' ', '_')` for underscores

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however it didn't work!    I tried several variations including the example you gave.                                      Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue str(!PlaceName!).replace(" ", "_") # String
ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)


Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue str(!Value!).replace(" ", "_") # String

ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)

Comment: Try double clicking the field name to put it in the expression; sometimes a dataset will have a field name prefix that doesn't show up in the attribute table. Also try changing the double quotes to single quotes. Also for the parser make sure you're using the PYTHON_9.3 option. Is the field calculator returning any values at all?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the field calculator for replace at all.

You can just use the Find & Replace tool which is accessed from the attribute-table which has the search/replace function the same way as in Excel, for example.

It also works for all columns simultaneously or can be set to search for whole values etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need this to work inside of model builder, also I am not trying to change the value in the table. Ultimately both the value with the space and the value without a space are going to be used as inputs in a later portion of the model.